# Multi insert from Power BI to Power Apps insertion

Tags: powerapps

### Scenario

We have a basic Power App embedded within Power BI. Currently end-users can select a single row within a PBI table visual which then populates several fields within Power App with the selected row's data.

### Question

Does Power App have the capability to allow end-users to select multiple rows within the the PBI table visual and submit all at once through the Power App?